# iScroll move header up or down while scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, scroll, iscroll

I am trying to build a function which moves the header 45px up while scrolling down and reverse. It should be like the facebook header mobile app, or the address-bar of chrome mobile browser or safari mobile browser.
I am using for the scrolling the iScroll plugin and i managed to let the header moving up while scrolling down and moving down again while scrolling up.
But sometimes it is not working. It stuck while scrolling.

This is my JS code:

```
function updatePosition () {
        var wrapperPosition         = this.y;
        var lastStopPosition        = $('#header').attr('data-last-value');
        var distance                = wrapperPosition - lastStopPosition;

        var getMatrixStyle          = window.getComputedStyle($('#header').get(0));
        var getMatrix               = new WebKitCSSMatrix(getMatrixStyle.webkitTransform);
        var matrixPositionHeader    = getMatrix.m42;

        var moveUp                  = matrixPositionHeader - 1;
        var moveDown                = matrixPositionHeader + 1;

        if(wrapperPosition >= -45 && wrapperPosition <= 0 && distance < 0) {
            $('#header').css({ '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,' + wrapperPosition + 'px)' });
        } 
        else if(wrapperPosition <= -46 && distance < 0) {
            $('#header').css({ '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,-45px)' });
        } 
        else if(wrapperPosition <= -46 && distance > 0) {
            if(matrixPositionHeader <= -1){
                $('#header').css({ '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,' + moveDown + 'px)' });
            } 
            else if(matrixPositionHeader == 0){
                $('#header').removeAttr('style');
            }
        } 
        else if(distance > 0 && distance <= 45){
            if(matrixPositionHeader <= -1){
                $('#header').css({ '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,' + moveDown + 'px)' });
            } 
            else if(matrixPositionHeader == 0){
                $('#header').removeAttr('style');
            }
        }

        writeposition.innerHTML     = this.y>>0;
        writeposition3.innerHTML    = distance;
    }

    function scrollStart() {
        var getMatrixStyle          = window.getComputedStyle($('#innerwrapper').get(0));
        var getMatrix               = new WebKitCSSMatrix(getMatrixStyle.webkitTransform);
        var matrixPositionWrapper   = getMatrix.m42;

        writeposition2.innerHTML    = matrixPositionWrapper;
    }

    function scrollEnd() {
        var getMatrixStyle          = window.getComputedStyle($('#innerwrapper').get(0));
        var getMatrix               = new WebKitCSSMatrix(getMatrixStyle.webkitTransform);
        var matrixPositionWrapper   = getMatrix.m42;

        $('#header').attr('data-last-value', matrixPositionWrapper);

        writeposition4.innerHTML    = matrixPositionWrapper;
    }

    function loaded () {
        var myScroll;
        writeposition = document.getElementById('position');
        writeposition2 = document.getElementById('position2');
        writeposition3 = document.getElementById('position3');
        writeposition4 = document.getElementById('position4');

        myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { 
                                             probeType: 3, 
                                             mouseWheel: true,
                                             speedRatioY: 40
                                            });

        myScroll.on('scrollStart', scrollStart);
        myScroll.on('scroll', updatePosition);
        myScroll.on('scrollEnd', scrollEnd);
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

my HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top: 110px;z-index:100; left: 120px;">Innerwrapper Y position: <strong id="position">0</strong> px</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top: 130px;z-index:100; left: 120px;">Start position: <strong id="position2">0</strong> px</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top: 150px;z-index:100; left: 120px;">Distance betweent start/stop position: <strong id="position3">0</strong> px</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top: 170px;z-index:100; left: 120px;">Last stop position: <strong id="position4">0</strong> px</div>
    <header id="header" role="banner" data-last-value="0">
        <div class="header-main"></div>
        <!-- end header main --> 
        <div class="header-bar"></div>
        <!-- end header bar -->
    </header>
    <!-- end header -->

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="innerwrapper">
            <ul>
                <li>Content</li>
                .....
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end inner wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper -->
```

Here is a link for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/bP9hy/1/

To see the problem, try to scroll a few times up and down but to stop scrolling in between (e.g. scroll 120px down and stop. Then scroll up again).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Km9qL/

i made it in a few minutes. it uses css and js(it wont cause issues on scrolling) :) and it css works better imo :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. but this is not really what i am looking for. as soon you start scrolling (e.g. 1px) the header starts to move up or down. what i was trying is to move the header with the scrolling position. when a user scrolls 30px down, the header moves 30px up.